# GET('/test') path in the users controller in Nestjs, but it doesn't work

Tags: controller, nestjs

- users.controller.ts -

  `export class UsersController { constructor( ... ) {}}` 
  @Post("/test")
  test() {
  console.log('aa');
  return "success";
  }

  @Get('/test')
  test2() {
  console.log('aa');
  return "success";
  }`

If I test the above path with postman

GET /users/test -> {
"statusCode": 404,
"message": "Not Found"
} 
POST /users/test -> success

It works like this from a moment in the middle of writing the code.
Paths such as GET /{nickname} in the same Users controller work normally.
It's my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, so I couldn't write a pretty post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no user with the nickname test.

The paths `GET /test` and `GET /{nickname}` conflict with each other. You can use `GET /-/test` path to resolve the conflict.